# Can a Marionette.js Behavior trigger an Event?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, mobile-website, backbone-views

I have a Behavior in Marionette that handles the logic for detecting swipe events. My subviews each incorporate this behavior to know when a swipe gesture has occurred on them. My question is once my Behavior has determined a swipe has occurred, how does it get this information out to its View?

Even better if the Behavior could trigger some event that could be listened for, not by its corresponding View but by the Layout View (the parent view).

Is this sort of thing possible? Thanks!

Comment: What version of Marionette are you using?

Comment: I think I found the answer: Apparently, if you add a Behavior to a View, that Behavior has a reference to its own view: `this.view`. So, to trigger an event, just use `this.view.triggerMethod()`. The event triggered will get picked up by any ancestor views listening to it. Thats how it seems to work to me. Anyone know if I'm missing something?

Comment: Lol. I just saw you comment after submitting *that* solution! I guess, in the answer you'll have the strategy formalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by no means the only solution, but a very Marionettish approach. The two elements that make this solution possible are

1. The introduction in Marionette 2.4.0 of `Layout.childEvents`. An event triggered in a LayoutView's child views will bubble up to the parent LayoutView using `LayoutView.childEvents.`
2. Every Behavior has a reference to the view instance it is attached to. We can trigger events on this view *from within* the Behavior

So here's the idea. First let's set up the event we expect the behavior to emit in the LayoutView.

```
Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  // This callback will be called whenever a child emits a `view:swipe` event
  childEvents: {
    'view:swipe': 'onChildSwipe'
  }
});
```

Then, we set up the swipe handler in the Behavior to trigger the event *on the instance view* it's in. This event will first hit the view, and will continue to bubble up to the LayoutView where `LayoutView.onChildSwipe` will handle the event.

```
Marionette.Behavior.extend({
    handleSwipe: function(e) {
        // Do processing...
        this.view.trigger('view:swipe', data);
    }
});
```

You may have multiple sub-views in your LayoutView, and you may want to handle swipes differently. There many apporoaches to how to identify the views. The most general, is to send the view in the trigger, so you can modify `handleSwipe` above like this,

```
    handleSwipe: function(e) {
        // Do processing...
        this.view.trigger('view:swipe', this.view, data);
    }
```

and your `LayoutView.onChildSwipe` would be responsible for identifying the view (like by looking at its `model.id` for example) and acting accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation of how this all works! It works great and I also didn't think about sending the view with the trigger!

Comment: You're most welcome. And it's the contributors to Marionette that we should also be grateful for, for making these excellent features possible.